# Network communication between google instance to internal network

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I use Google App Engine to deploy a website. The domain of my application is XXX.appspot.com. In the website I created, I can send SOAP messages. I want to send message to an internal network on Google Compute Engine. In Google Compute I created a network and a vitual instance with the internal address X.X.X.X and external address Y.Y.Y.Y.

My question is how can I send message to my virtual instance X.X.X.X with the web application XXX.appspot.com.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can configure your SOAP client to use the public IP of you Compute Engine instance(when I hope you have a SOAP endpoint).

Take in mind that isn't possibile create a sort of "private network" from appengine to compute engine so the compute engine instance need to be reached from "internet" and you must authenticate requests.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Aqquadro,
I was unclear in some detail:
I need my application at 
XXX.appspot.com 
To send SOAP messages to my Google virtual instance 
X.X.X.X (and external address Y.Y.Y.1)
Which can be routed onwards to internal nodes on the subnet Z.Z.Z.2-255

Comment: Doesnt the answer cover this already? You cant use the internal addresses. Connect like any other client using the external ip.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answers, I did not know it is impossible to do a connection between GAE and GCE (private network). So I have to pass through the public address of my VM instance.